# Where should the business logic go (action creators or reducers) in react using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

*There are possible duplicates of this question but they don't quiet answer my question well. So I decided to start a new thread.*

So I am trying to create a simple basket component for an e-commerce application....

Following is the code for reducers and action files:

**actions.js**

```
export const incrementQuantitySuccess = (basketProducts) =>{
    return {
        type: actionTypes.INCREMENT_QUANTITY_SUCCESS,
        basketProducts:basketProducts
    }
}

export const incrementQuantity = (line) => {
    return (dispatch,getState) => {  

       /*LOGIC for increment quantity*/
        const basketProducts = getState().basket.productsInBasket;
        const updatedBasketProducts = basketProducts.map((product) =>{        
            if (product.id === line.id){
                product.quantity += 1;
                product.total = product.quantity * product.price;
            }

            return product;
        });
        /***************/  

        dispatch(incrementQuantitySuccess(updatedBasketProducts));
  }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
const incrementQuantitySuccess = ( state, action ) => {
    return updateObject(state,{
        productsInBasket:action.basketProducts,
        loading:false
    });
}

const reducer = (state= initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.GET_BASKET: return getBasket(state,action);
        case actionTypes.INCREMENT_QUANTITY_SUCCESS: return incrementQuantitySuccess(state,action);
        default:return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Right now I have put the increment quantity logic in my action.js file.

I found various advises regarding keeping a balance between reducers and action creators when it comes to distributing business logic, where as some told to keep reducers stupid and dumb.

My question is where should the Logic for increment go? I went through couple of articles,on redux.js.org, on where the business logic should be but I am still not clear about it.

Also is this particular use-case I am not sure if I need middleware like redux-logic.

I am new to react. Kindly guide regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code in the question is specific to redux-thunk but it's not mentioned explicitly. Yes, you could possibly benefit from redux-logic.

Comment: Can you explain it with by modifying above example?

Comment: Basically, `LOGIC for increment quantity` should go to `transform` Redux logic for INCREMENT_QUANTITY action (you won't even need separate INCREMENT_QUANTITY and INCREMENT_QUANTITY_SUCCESS actions). That's a good thing about it, it's very straightforward. Consider asking a new question if you will have specific problems with doing that. Since current question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it would be hard to give a useful and workable answer.

Comment: Thanks but i think i am gonna go with custom middlewares..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of practices says that you should keep your reducers and actions **pure** and the real side-effect should happen inside your middlewares. With this approach you will keep the actions and reducers nice and clean and you can fully focus on your middlewares because they will become the only place, where side-effects can happen.

I was really amazed when I watched presentation from Nir Kaufman and I'm encouraging you to watch his speak at ReactNYC [Advanced Redux Patterns - Nir Kaufman @ ReactNYC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUuic7mEs-s). This video helped me a lot when I was struggling with Redux the most.

Also there is second speak about Redux and middlewares from Nir. You can check the second one here [Advanced Redux: Design Patterns and Practices - Nir Kaufman | JSHeroes 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gl3cCB_26M&t=1044s)

Hope it will help!

Comment: I have started looking at middlewares as a general-use feature rather than something advanced....your answer and Nir Kaufman's talks gave a better explanation as to why logic should go in middlewares. I will b going with custom middlewares since even the third  party like redux logic more or less follow the same philosophy as Nir Kaufman's.Thanks.marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck!